# How do I run a line through my text next to the checkbox if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, addeventlistener

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var mylist = $('#input').val();
    $('#myUL').prepend('<li><input type="checkbox" id = "check" name="interest" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()">' + mylist + '</li>');

  });

});

function toggleBoxVisibility() {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {

    document.getElementsByTagName("LI").style.visibility = "visible";

  } else {

    document.getElementById("myUL").style.visibility = "hidden";

  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  /* make the list items unselectable
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
}

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#myUL {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 27%;
}

.claim {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#check {
  margin-right: -190px;
  margin-left: -190px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login </title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <body>

    <div class="hero">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-2 text-center">To-Do</h1>

        <div class="row">
          <form id="form" class="col-lg-6 col-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a new task here">
              <span>
                                <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Add</button>
                            </span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <ul id="myUL">
          <li>Hit the gym </li>
          <li class="checked">Pay bills</li>
          <li>Meet George</li>
          <li>Buy eggs</li>

        </ul>

        <div class="row">
          <button id="btnClr" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto btnHide"> Remove Complete </button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

**I want to run a line through the text once it is selected and I am not sure how to do that. I have pasted most of my code above and I tried to toggle the visiblity of the list in order to make sure if the checking function works or not. The checking function works.  I just want some ideas of how should i strike through the text once the checkbox next to the box is selected. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer this article to done this task [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/). Anyway I try to use it and it works fine. Hope this one can give you some insight.

Add label on your jQuery code, `<label>' + mylist + '</label>` and looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var mylist = $('#input').val();
    $('#myUL').prepend('<li><input type="checkbox" id = "check" name="interest" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()"><label>' + mylist + '</label></li>');

  });
});
```

And add this line to your CSS:

```
input:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This inherits a serious flaw from the original code, you will end up with check boxes with duplicate id's, you should address that and have the label correctly associated with  the field by use of the `for` attribute.

Comment: Oh my bad, @JonP thanks for the insight. I just focuses on the CSS `input:checked` problem, yet this solution bring another serious problem lol.

Comment: No problem, your actual  CSS solution is what I would have done, it's just worth mentioning the big problem with duplicate ids.